# Why do I get 404 Error when using Google Classroom API?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-classroom

I am writing an app in PHP which will connect to my domains's Google Classroom.  However I get the following error when I try to do anything with the Google Classroom API:

```
Message: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/v1/courses?pageSize=100: (404) Not Found
```

My code so far:

```
$scopes = array(
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly'
);

$gServiceEmail = "random@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
$gServiceKey = file_get_contents("../path/to/cert.p12");

$client = new Google_Client();
$gAuth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $gServiceEmail,
  $scopes,
  $gServiceKey
);

$gAuth->sub = "user@mydomain.com";
$client->setAssertionCredentials($gAuth);

$service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
$results = $service->courses->listCourses();
```

I have enabled the scopes in the API Settings in the Google Admin Console for the service account and enabled the api in the developer console.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I think your endpoint is wrong according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/) of Classroom API. Try changing it to  https://classroom.googleapis.com

sample request:

```
GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?pageSize=100&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: I had an old version of the php client lib. Upgrading to the latest version resolved the issue as it uses the correct endpoint as you state in your answer

Answer (score 0):

**Course with id is not found.
For a list of courses, use the courses.list(), as shown in the following sample.**

```
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);

// Print the first 10 courses the user has access to.
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 10
);
$results = $service->courses->listCourses($optParams);

if (count($results->getCourses()) == 0) {
  print "No courses found.\n";
} else {
  print "Courses:\n";
  foreach ($results->getCourses() as $course) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $course->getName(), $course->getId());
  }
}
```

**References:**

https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/php?hl=en
https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-courses?hl=en